# Working with objects and autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

Basically, i want to achieve an autocomplete text box using jQuery's autocomplete function.

I have managed to get this working with a simple array of names, however i need to be able to store an id inside a hidden input field that corresponds to the search term selected.

Now i am very confused, being a php developer i have no real experience with javascript other then a simple ajax calls and simple jQuery effects.

So onkeyup this function runs:

```
function searchProviders(str) {

            var availableTags = [];

            if (str.length >= 4) {
                var term = str;
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "/services/search/",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    data: {
                        featureClass: "P",
                        style: "full",
                        maxRows: 50,
                        term: term
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        jQuery.each(data.results, function (key, data) {
                            //console.log(data.name);
                            var obj = {
                                serviceID: data.ID,
                                name: data.name
                            };
                            availableTags.push(obj);
                        })
                        test(availableTags);
                    }
                });
            }

        }
```

So when i console.log(data.name) i get a simple list of the names i need. Which when passed to my other function works fine. However when trying to send through an i as well i realised that javascript does not do associative arrays and uses 'objects' instead.

So instead i create an obj with the service id and name then push that into my availableTags array.

At this point when i console.log(availableTags) it reads like this.

[image]

Now with this info captured i want to do the autocomplete function and when the user clicks on the item they want i want to it to populate the text box as well as populating another hidden field with the id.

test():

```
        function test(test){
            var availableTags = [test];
            var Tags = availableTags[0];
            var searchTags = []
            jQuery.each(Tags, function(key,obj){
                jQuery.each(obj, function(key,value){
                    searchTags.push(value);
                });
            });
            jQuery( "#search" ).autocomplete({
                source: searchTags
            });
        }
```

Okay so now my auto complete works again, it shows the name in a drop down to select, this is because i have only added the names into searchTags, but how can i do this so that if they click onto a name it also stores the corresponding id elsewhere?

Comment: Rename the key and labels to: `label(name)` and `value(key)`. Check out the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yu93jux4/

Comment: @GuyT that would be perfect, if only it could keep label there but store the value in a hidden field

Answer (score 0):

If you can try adding jQuery's Select2 plugin, which does the stuff for you, then you don't need to worry about these. Just create a `<select></select>` and `<option></option>` tags from the PHP, with the `<option>`'s  value having the ID of the element, and execute a function like here:

```
<select name="item" id="item">
    <option value="item-1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="item-2">Item 2</option>
    <option value="item-3">Item 3</option>
    <option value="item-4">Item 4</option>
    <option value="item-5">Item 5</option>
</select>

$("#item").select2();
```

A snippet could be as follows:

```js
$(function () {
  $("#item").select2({
    tags: true,
    width: 200
  }).change(function () {
    $("#sel").html("Selected Values: " + $(this).val());
  });
});
```

```css
@import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css");
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
<select name="item" id="item" multiple>
  <option value="item-1">Item 1</option>
  <option value="item-2">Item 2</option>
  <option value="item-3">Item 3</option>
  <option value="item-4">Item 4</option>
  <option value="item-5">Item 5</option>
</select>
<div id="sel"></div>
```

Comment: i do not wish to have a select element as i am using <input type="text"> for the autocomplete

Comment: @MatthewSmart See it has generated a text input only!

Comment: but it has not made another input field with the id when selected

Comment: I don't understand. This is so much extendable. Lemme update the answer @MatthewSmart.

Comment: @MatthewSmart Have a look at the code after selecting an item. Is that what you want?

Comment: no, i need the value inside the textbox to be "item-1" however the id needs to be printed else where in a hidden field

Comment: Can you please clarify again?

Comment: okay, i have an array that looks like the picture in my question, now i want to display the name in the text box. but i want to be able to set a hidden text fields value to the serviceID

Comment: Is **that** input, a holder of multiple entries? Like `c51,c52` or just holds `c51`?

Comment: just one. all i want to do is select 1 name that displays and then the corresponding id in another input field so that when i send a post request of i have the id to work with

Comment: Right, select2 does that right? Why you don't wanna use this?

Comment: To be honest it would meaning rolling out change to around 30 sites which would take a while.

Comment: i have achieved what i needed to do now, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
var searches = new Array();
        var NoResultsLabel = "No Results";
        jQuery(function () {
            /* Auto complete desktop */
            jQuery("#search").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    if (request.term in searches) {
                        response(jQuery.map(searches[request.term].results, function (item) {
                            return {label: item.name, value: item.name, id: item.ID}
                        }));
                    }
                    else {
                        jQuery.ajax({
                            url: "/services/search/",
                            dataType: "jsonp",
                            data: {
                                featureClass: "P",
                                style: "full",
                                maxRows: 50,
                                term: request.term
                            },
                            success: function (data) {

                                searches[request.term] = data;
                                console.log(data);
                                //Return no results msg to give add location
                                if (!data.results.length) {
                                    data.results = [NoResultsLabel];
                                }
                                response(jQuery.map(data.results, function (item) {
                                    return {label: item.name, value: item.name, id: item.ID}
                                }));
                            }
                        });
                    }
                },
                delay: 500,
                minLength: 2,
                autoFocus: true,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    jQuery('#serviceID').attr('value',ui.item.id);
                    console.log('in the select:');
                    console.log(ui.item);
                }
            }).bind('focus', function () {
                jQuery(this).autocomplete("search");
            });
        });
```

This solved my problem, took ages but got there!